# 10.4.24-MariaDB - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mariadb

In `person_addresses` table i am getting error `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`. My Version is `10.4.24-MariaDB`

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  bio text DEFAULT NULL,
  dob date DEFAULT NULL,
  gender enum('Male','Female','Other') NOT NULL,
  status tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
  UNIQUE KEY email (email),
  UNIQUE KEY phone (phone)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE person_addresses (
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL ,
  address text NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  UNIQUE KEY uc_person_address (person_id,address),
  CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons(person_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**More Detailed Error**

````
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2023-01-11 12:41:52 0x421c Error in foreign key constraint of table `test`.`person_addresses`:
There is no index in table ```test``.``person_addresses``` where the columns appear
as the first columns. Constraint:
 FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons (person_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/ for correct foreign key definition.Create  table `test`.`person_addresses` with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns near ' FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons (person_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4'.
````

Comment: Is there any one please help me

Comment: I tested this in MySQL 8.0.31, and there is no foreign key error. There is a problem with creating an index on the `address` text column, but if there's a foreign key error, it's not caused by the code you have shown above.

Comment: I have tested it on Mysql workbench and PHPMyadmin. Both are showing same error. Mya be there is any typo or verion or something.

Comment: @BillKarwin and thanks for the book SQL ANTI Patterns. I read that book 2 times and made notes that helped me a lot.

Comment: @Bill Karwin it is reproducible https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9AQkooj

Comment: As bill pointed out earlier there is a problem creating uc_person_address which mariadb fails to spot when key is unique, when key is not unique an error is thrown, the FK error appears to be a poor spot by mariadb and goes away if you define address as varchar(30) for example..

Comment: @P.Salmon Very strange problem hard to know. Database provider must be more specific with errors.

Comment: You should check bug reports, test in dbfiddle in a later version and if you still think this an issue raise a bug report. Otherwise you can only work around it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a matching bug report in MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29717

The issue is that if the index required for the foreign key is very large, the index is created automatically. But this fails if that index is larger than the index size limit for the storage engine (this should be 3072 bytes in the version of MariaDB you are using, because it defaults to DYNAMIC row format with [innodb_large_prefix](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_large_prefix)=on). The `text` type in your index is too large to be indexed without defining an index prefix. But foreign keys can't use indexes defined with index prefixes.

Unfortunately, because foreign keys are implemented deep in the storage engine, there is little opportunity for a more informative error message to be revealed. This is a problem with the implementation of pluggable storage engines.

The solution in your case should be to change the `address` column type. It cannot be `text`, it can only be a `varchar` that is not too long for the index prefix length limit.

For example, I tested with MariaDB 10.4. https://dbfiddle.uk/5jTX8iFt It fails if `address` is `text`, and it works fine if `address` is `varchar(255)`. I did not test other lengths, I'll leave that to you.

I doubt you need `text` for an address anyway. Does anyone have an address that requires 64KB?